# Change math font for figures only (including TikZ environments within figures)

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, math-mode, sans-serif

In my document, I want the main text to be in the `times` font, and the math to be in the `txfonts` font. This I can do with the help of the `txfonts` package. However, I want **everything** that shows up in my figures to be sans serif, including the math. So far I've been able to change the text font to sans serif but I also want to change the math font to a sans serif, both in the caption and the figure itself (where I use TikZ).

Here's a minimal (non-working) example that needs tweaking. The problem is the math within the figure and the caption which now is `txfonts`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%This package is used to get sans serif for regular text in captions.
\usepackage[font=sf]{caption}
%This package is used to get times for the main text and txfonts for math.
\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}
\begin{document}
Main text is supposed to be times. Math in main text is supposed to be     txfonts: $1+1=3$.
\begin{figure}
%Here I invoke the font option to make text within TikZ sans serif.
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\node at (0,0) {Sans Serif}; 
\node at (0,1) {Sans Serif Math: $5=3$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Figure caption text is supposed to be sans serif. Math in figure   capture text is supposed to be sans serif: $3+1=4.5$.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`sansmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sansmath) package in conjunction the [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg) and [`everyhook`](http://ctan.org/pkg/everyhook) packages to change the math within the figures only. This solution inherits all of the problems associated with sans math as implemented by the `sansmath` package. (See its documentation for details.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%This package is used to get sans serif for regular text in captions.
\usepackage[font=sf]{caption}
%This package is used to get times for the main text and txfonts for math.
\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}
\usepackage{float} % to easily modify floats
\usepackage{etoolbox} % nice command patching
\usepackage{sansmath} % sans serif math
\usepackage{everyhook} % nice \every... patching
% restyle figures to make \everymath=\sansmath (float package)
\restylefloat{figure}
\floatevery{figure}{\PushPreHook{math}{\sansmath}}
% undo the change to \everymath at the end of the figure (etoolbox)
\apptocmd{\endfigure}{\PopPreHook{math}}{}{}

\begin{document}
Main text is supposed to be times. Math in main text is supposed to be     txfonts: $1+1=3$.
\begin{figure}[h]
%Here I invoke the font option to make text within TikZ sans serif.
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]

\node[draw] at (0,0) {Sans Serif}; 
\node[draw] at (0,1) {Sans Serif Math: $5=3$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Figure caption text is supposed to be sans serif. 
 Math in figure   caption text is supposed to be sans serif: $3+1=4.5$.}
\end{figure}

This is some math after the figure $3 + 2 = 5$. It is back to serifs.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [amsmath](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) to influence the math font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[font=sf]{caption}
\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}
\begin{document}
With amsmath:
\[ \mathbf{bf\ Bold\ 3+5=8} \]
\[ \mathrm{rm\ Roman\ 3+5=8} \]
\[ \mathcal{cal\ Caligraphy\ 3+5=8} \]
\[ \mathsf{sf\ Sans\ Serif\ 3+5=8} \]
\[ \mathtt{tt\ Truetype\ 3+5=8} \]
\[ \mathit{it\ Italic\ 3+5=8} \]
\end{document}
```

Theres also fonts for Blackboard Bold ([mathbb](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/amsfonts), for denoting number systems), Fraktur ([mathfrak](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/amsfonts)) and Euler script ([euscript](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/amsfonts/latex/euscript.sty))

[image: Example]

Comment: I'm not going to use this now since it seems to require more coding than Alan's suggestion but thanks for the input. I'll definitely try to remember this for future use.