# Switching math fonts and back to normal fails in figures?

Tags: pgfplots, unicode-math

For my current document I want to use a normal serif font for the main text. Most diagrams from other sources and myself are with sans serif fonts (TeX Gyre Heros). Now I want to use `pgfplots` to create 
figures using these fonts but keep the math in the main text in the normal font. Something similar has been achieved with `sansmath` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26145/change-math-font-for-figures-only-including-tikz-environments-within-figures) but this does not switch to completely different font, as I am trying here. I thought with `unicode-math` I can switch back and forth easily but the switching back part fails.

My MWE looks as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \sffamily
    \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Heros}  
    \setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin, Latin, greek, Greek}]{texgyreheros-italic.otf} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot [blue] coordinates { (0,0) (1,2) };
        \end{axis}
        \node at (4, 1) { $\Delta T_{\mathrm S}$};
        \node at (2, 5) {normal sans serif text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \rmfamily
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}  
\caption{Some caption text.}
\end{figure}

Normal text in Latin Modern Roman here but math fails unless the next line is used.
%\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math} 
\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

and gives the following output:

[image]
Thank you for any hints, why the switching back fails and comments in general how this might be improved.

Comment: Try to shift `\rmfamily\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math} ` after the `figure` environment. Does it helps?

Comment: If you want to switch between math versions you should better declare a \mathversion. Imho the newest unicode-math contains the necessary code.

Comment: You can't use TeX Gyre Heros as math font, because it lacks the basic math functionalities.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: We need an answer ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I don't have one: It is not difficult to set up a mathversion with another math font, but the use of TeX Gyre and the range part has some side effects.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments `TeX Gyre Heros` is not a math fonts and this is what is causing the strange errors.  However, you can use the `mathastext` package overcome this.  The following demonstrates its use with `lualatex`.  The order in the preamble is crucial.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}\Mathastext[Heros]
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \MTversion{Heros}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[font=\sffamily]
      \addplot [blue] coordinates { (0,0) (1,2) };
    \end{axis}
    \node at (4, 1) { $\Delta T_{\mathrm S}$}; \node at (2, 5)
    {normal sans serif text};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \MTversion{normal}
  \caption{Some caption text.}
\end{figure}

Normal text in Latin Modern Roman here but math fails unless the next
line is used.
\begin{equation}
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you might have been the first ever non-sponsored user of `\MTversion` command, besides the package author `;-)`.