# pst-circ monospaced labels

Tags: math-mode, pstricks, pst-circ

How can I make all labels in my circuit monospaced?
I found this: [Can I change all math output to use monospaced text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62978/can-i-change-all-math-output-to-use-monospaced-text)
but this also affects my equations outside figures.

```
    \documentclass{minimal}
    \usepackage{pst-circ}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \everymath{\mathtt{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam\relax}\aftergroup\tmp}}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \begin{document}
    \setbox0\hbox{$ $}
        \begin{pspicture}(5,2)
        \psset{linewidth=1pt}
        \pnode(0,1){A}
        \pnode(3,1){B}
        \pnode(5,1){C}
        \newdiode(A)(B){$D_1$}
        \resistor(B)(C){$R_1$}
        \end{pspicture}
    $ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} $
    \end{document}
```

Can I redefine pst-circ label command to use monospaced font?

Comment: What about just using `$\mathtt{D_1}$` and `$\mathtt{R_1}$`?

Comment: The final circuits are far more complicated and there is an exact solution for sans serif fonts: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26145/change-math-font-for-figures-only-including-tikz-environments-within-figures however I can't merge two mentioned methods to work together.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong order; first you have to set `\everymath` and then set a box to initialize the mechanism. If you set `\everymath` inside the `pspicture`, the effect will vanish with its end.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,2)
\everymath{\mathtt{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam\relax}\aftergroup\tmp}}
\sbox0{$$}% initialize tt for all math formulas
\psset{linewidth=1pt}
\pnode(0,1){A}
\pnode(3,1){B}
\pnode(5,1){C}
\newdiode(A)(B){$D_1$}
\resistor(B)(C){$R_1$}
\end{pspicture}
$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that using the `minimal` class is not recommended for making examples; use `article` or `standalone`.

---

You can define a handier command to get this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ttmath}{%
  \everymath{\mathtt{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam\relax}\aftergroup\tmp}}%
  \sbox0{$$}% initialize tt for all math formulas
}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,2)
\ttmath
\psset{linewidth=1pt}
\pnode(0,1){A}
\pnode(3,1){B}
\pnode(5,1){C}
\newdiode(A)(B){$D_1$}
\resistor(B)(C){$R_1$}
\end{pspicture}
$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now can I use it with everyhook package?

Comment: @user15941 The important thing is to assign `\everymath` locally in the `pspicture` environment. I added something.

Answer (score 1):

try the latest version of `pst-circ.tex` from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pst-circ/. It knows two additional arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\begin{document}
\psset{mathlabel,labelstyle=\tt} %%%%
  \begin{pspicture}(5,2)
    \psset{linewidth=1pt}
    \pnode(0,1){A}
    \pnode(3,1){B}
    \pnode(5,1){C}
    \newdiode(A)(B){D_1}%% without $..$
    \resistor(B)(C){R_1}
    \end{pspicture}
    $ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} $
\end{document}
```

[image]